# error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, inheritance, linker

IN my VC++ code which was compiling fine earlier, I have added a function X() like this:

```
In the file BaseCollection.h
class Base
{
// code
virtual HRESULT X();
//code
};


IN the file DerivedCollection.h
class Derived:public Base
{
    HRESULT X();

}

In the file DerivedCollection.cpp
HRESULT Derived::X
{
// definition of Derived here. 
}
```

Have included the header files also properly in the .cpp file.
But still I don't understand for what reason I am getting the link error:

> error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual long
>   __thiscall Base::X()" (?X@Base@@UAEJI@Z)

I am really trying hard to fix this bug. Can anyone kindly help me in getting this issue resolved. 
Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you implemented `X()` in `Base`? You need to do that, or make it pure virtual:

```
class Base
{
// code
virtual HRESULT X() = 0; //pure virtual. Base doesn't need to implement it.
//code
};
```

Also, your definition of `X()` in `Derived` looks wrong. You probable need something like this:

```
HRESULT Derived::X()
{
// definition of Derived here. 
}
```

Comment: Yes thanks I got rid of link errors. :) thank u so much for such a speedy response.

Answer (score 2):

You're never defining the function `X`:

```
HRESULT Base::X()
{
// definition of X 
}
```

You'll also need a definition for `Derived::X()` since that too is `virtual`.

Comment: Yes thanks I got rid of link errors. :) thank u so much for such a speedy response.  Hope stackoverflow could allow to select both the answers as the correct ones. :)